# C# iterate over two lists - exchangable inner / outer loop

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach

I need to iterate over three lists and process each combination. Order of the most outer and second level loop (`list1` / `list2`) depends on some ordering rules.
Moreover I have some logic before and after the last (`list3`) foreach loop.
`ProcesPair` method uses all three items and depends on their order.

```
        if (order == Order.Right)
        {
            foreach (var a in list1)
            {
                foreach (var b in list2)
                {
                    DoSomethingBefore();

                    foreach (var c in list3)
                    {
                        ProcessPair(a, b, c);
                    }

                    DoSomethingAfter();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (order == Order.Down)
        {
            foreach (var b in list2)
            {
                foreach (var a in list1)
                {
                    DoSomethingBefore();

                    foreach (var c in list3)
                    {
                        ProcessPair(a, b, c);
                    }

                    DoSomethingAfter();
                }
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to make it somehow more elegant? I meen, how to reduce loops in code, something like `Zip` function but each with each other.

Comment: does `ProcessPair` use `c` in any way?

Comment: Oh yes, I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: if items of list1 and list2 were compatible types of an `IEnumerable`, you could write the loops just once, swapping assignments of list1 and list2 before.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not of the same type.

Comment: All combinations of list1 and list2?  The way that zip works (assuming Python) is that the ith element in each list is combined into a tuple.

Comment: I am guessing you know that working code questions are usually better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK I know about 'CodeReview', but I wasn't sure, if some specific C# method or something could solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested loops are indicator for LINQ [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx). Hence the equivalent of the sample code could be like this:

```
var pairs = 
    order == Order.Right ? list1.SelectMany(a => list2, (a, b) => new { a, b }) ?
    order == Order.Down ? list2.SelectMany(b => list1, (b, a) => new { a, b }) :
    null;

if (pairs != null)
{
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        DoSomethingBefore();
        foreach (var c in list3)
        {
            ProcessPair(pair.a, pair.b, c);
        }
        DoSomethingAfter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I felt in love with this `SelectMany` pattern!  Do you have any recommendation, when it is not convenient to use it? Because I am atracted by idea of refactoring all of my multi-level `foreach` loops :).

Comment: Well, it's not so concise if used for more than two values. Also has some small overhead of creating a heap allocation (although short lived). Other than that, it's quite convenient :)

Answer (score 1):

Or just refactor the repeating code into a separate method:

```
void ProcessPairs(List<int> list1, List<int> list2, List<int> list3)
{
    foreach (var a in list1)
        foreach (var b in list2)
        {
            DoSomethingBefore();

            foreach (var c in list3)
                ProcessPair(a, b, c);

            DoSomethingAfter();
        }        
}
```

and then

```
    if (order == Order.Right)
        ProcessPairs(list1, list2, list3);
    else if (order == Order.Down)
        ProcessPairs(list2, list1, list3);
```

Comment: OK I should mention that lists are not of the same type.